# How does the range of Wings of Flurry work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Wings of Flurry from Races of the Dragon is a great blasting spell. Its area is a 30-ft radius burst, and its range is 30 ft.

How is this supposed to work? Can I only cast the spell on my own square to get the full blast area? Do I really have to compute the union of the two 30-ft-radius spheres on the battlegrid to find out which squares are affected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, both the origin point and the spell's effect are constrained by the range ([SRD, "Magic Overview", "Range"](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#range), emphasis mine):

> A spell’s range is the maximum distance from you that the spell’s effect can occur, as well as the maximum distance at which you can designate the spell’s point of origin. **If any portion of the spell’s area would extend beyond this range, that area is wasted.**

Calculating this is somewhat annoying, but isn't too hard if you use templates, as there are no "partial" squares of effect. Use two 30' radius templates overlapping to find the parts of the second inside the first. To get the full area of effect, yes, you'd have to cast it on your own square.

As far as I can tell, this combination of range and area of effect are intended to let you make the spell selectively directional (perhaps to spare allies) at the cost of reduced area of effect, without overly complicating the spell itself.

Comment: Wings of Flurry already affect *designated targets*, so sparing allies isn't a problem. I'd guess someone just forgot to add "centered on you" to the statistic block. (Probably the same sleep-deprived writer as the one who forgot to add a damage cap to the spell.)

Comment: @Ernir It also says it hits "every target in range" before that rather than specifying enemies, leading me to believe "designated targets" after is just a clumsy back-reference to "every target in range", friend or foe. The lack of targeting procedure or numbers makes that seem likely to me too, but I'll agree it's poorly written and could be intended to mean something else.